# Numpy: is there any difference between ix_ and ogrid?

Tags: python, numpy

The title says it all: any differences between np.ogrid and np.ix_ ? For instance the output of `ogrid[0:9.,0:6.]` and `ix_(r_[0:9.],r_[0:6.])` is the same.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The docs don't state that one is an alias of the other, so I'm going to assume that they're indeed different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't the same thing, but can produce the same arrays.

One's a class instance using `[]`, the other a function.  One produces a list, the other a tuple.  One takes slice notation directly (a consequence of the `[]` notation, the other requires lists or arrays, or the output of the `np.r_` object.

```
In [8]: np.ogrid[0:9.,0:6.]                                                                    
Out[8]: 
[array([[0.],
        [1.],
        [2.],
        [3.],
        [4.],
        [5.],
        [6.],
        [7.],
        [8.]]), array([[0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.]])]

In [10]: np.ix_(np.r_[0:9.],np.r_[0:6.])                                                       
Out[10]: 
(array([[0.],
        [1.],
        [2.],
        [3.],
        [4.],
        [5.],
        [6.],
        [7.],
        [8.]]), array([[0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.]]))
```

`meshgrid` can also produce the list:

```
In [14]: np.meshgrid(np.arange(9.),np.arange(6.),indexing='ij',sparse=True)                    
Out[14]: 
[array([[0.],
        [1.],
        [2.],
        [3.],
        [4.],
        [5.],
        [6.],
        [7.],
        [8.]]), array([[0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.]])]
```

You can also make the arrays 'directly':

```
In [15]: (np.arange(9.).reshape(-1,1), np.arange(6.).reshape(1,-1))                            
Out[15]: 
(array([[0.],
        [1.],
        [2.],
        [3.],
        [4.],
        [5.],
        [6.],
        [7.],
        [8.]]), array([[0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.]]))
```

`np.arange` and `np.r_` can produce the same array, though `r_` provides a few more bells and whistles.

You can read the code yourself at: `numpy/lib/index_tricks.py`

Comment: Thank you for the great reply ! Since then I also noticed `np.ix_` can do things like `np.ix_([0,1,3], [0,1,3])` which 'np.ogrid' does not seem to do.